# $D:=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ is complete?

Tags: metric-spaces

How to conclude whether the set

$D:=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ is complete ?

I thought in the straight forward process of using a Cauchy sequence say $(x_n,y_n)$ then could not proceed further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Consider $(x_n,y_n) = (0,1-1/n)$.

Answer (score 3):

The space is not complete. Any Cauchy sequence in the disk that converges to a point on the boundary will provide a counterexample.

For example, consider $a_n = (1-1/n, 0)$. This sequence is Cauchy, since if $\epsilon>0$. we have $d(a_m,a_n)<\epsilon$ whenever $m,n>1/\epsilon$. The sequence converges to $(1,0)$, which is outside $D$, so $D$ is not complete.